# Following multiple Twitter searches efficiently

Tags: twitter, search

How can I efficiently follow a bunch of Twitter searches, and see live results come up?  They removed the RSS functionality so I can't just plug in a bunch of searches to my RSS reader like I used to be able to.

Keep in mind that I'm trying to follow search terms, not specific users or tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to answer this question without knowing more about your particular needs.

[Tweetdeck](http://www.tweetdeck.com/desktop/) is a popular application (recently acquired by Twitter) that allows you to subscribe to multiple searches and follow them in real-time:

- http://www.tweetdeck.com/features/follow-topics-in-real-time-with-saved-searches/index.html

However there are, like, a thousand Twitter clients, so there may be others that suit you better.

Comment: Hmm, so Tweetdeck adds a column for each search. What if I want to track > 20 searches, though? Anyhing that could combine them into one feed or otherwise display them conveniently?

Comment: @babonk: Tweetdeck allows advanced searches: keyword OR otherkeyword OR "an exact phrase"

Comment: Sure, but the searches I have to make won't fit in one big advanced search.  Twitter sets limits on the size of searches.. So I need about 20 big searches to follow

Comment: If you have the budget, there are an equally large number of paid social media monitoring tools available. You could try Alterian SM2, Radian 6 or a bunch of others: http://www.socialmedia.biz/2011/01/12/top-20-social-media-monitoring-vendors-for-business/

Again, if you don't state your specific needs, then the question can't be well answered, and just becomes a list of favourite tools.

Comment: Twetdeck actually seems to do the job because it notifies you when one of the column gets an update.  Thanks